# stored procedure for calculating a sum - MySQL 5

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

getting a 'invalid use of group function'

just trying to sum the values of all the column values for 'weight' in a table:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE v_finished int DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_weight int DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE totalWeight int DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE weight_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT weight FROM users_teachers;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;
OPEN weight_cursor;

get_weight: LOOP
FETCH weight_cursor into v_weight;
IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
        LEAVE get_weight;
    END IF;
SET totalWeight = totalWeight + v_weight;



END LOOP get_weight;

CLOSE weight_cursor;

END
```

UPDATE: the problem now is that v_weight is always = 0. that is, it is not returning the values from the DB table, some of which are non-zero

Comment: @Guneli inno-db, mysql 5

Comment: I do not know much about inno-db, mysql 5 but I think that this "SET totalWeight = SUM(v_weight);" should be something like "SET totalWeight = totalWeight + v_weight;"

Comment: ...Why are you doing this with a `CURSOR`, of all things?  You'd be better off with a regular (set-based) statement; for one things, it should likely be faster.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse so the eventual goal is to add a scheduler, and have the procedure update the column weight every so often with some specified value calculated in the procedure. at the moment, im just taking some baby steps to see how this thing works

Comment: @compguy24, have you tried the change suggested by me?

Comment: @Guneli just tried it, now no error. however, the SUM is always outputting to zero. am i not fetching my rows correctly?

Comment: Are you sure that your query returns data?

Comment: @Guneli, no, I am not sure. how can i check?

Comment: You should just execute "SELECT weight FROM users_teachers" in your db and see if some data is returned.

Comment: @Guneli ok, yes I have values. v_weight is always = 0. it is not not being filled with the values in the table.

Comment: How have you checked that v_weight is always equal to 0?

Comment: @Guneli that's what i don't want -- i want v_weight to be equal to the db values. sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52111/discussion-between-compguy24-and-guneli)

Answer (score 1):

So, as the first error was in the SUM function. Please, try this:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_weight INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE totalWeight INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE weight_cursor CURSOR FOR 
   SELECT weight FROM users_teachers;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;
OPEN weight_cursor;

get_weight: 
LOOP
FETCH weight_cursor into v_weight;
IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
        LEAVE get_weight;
END IF;
SET totalWeight = totalWeight + v_weight; 

END LOOP get_weight;

CLOSE weight_cursor;

END
```

Comment: @compguy24, can you, please show us your input data?